# Create custom alert dialog from Chrome Extension background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to be able to display a styled alert dialog - the alert dialog is called from the background script of a Chrome Extension.

I have the following code in the background script:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (details) {

  chrome.windows.getCurrent({}, function (currentWindow) {

    const currentWindowId = currentWindow.id;

    chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {

      const myTab = tabs.find(function (tab) {
        return String(tab.url).trim().startsWith(sumanExtensionURL);
      });

      if (myTab) {

        chrome.tabs.update(myTab.id, {highlighted: true});
        if (String(myTab.windowId).trim() !== String(currentWindowId).trim()) {
          alert('Suman Chrome Extension already opened in another window.');
        }
      }
      else {
        console.log('no existing tab found, opening a new one.');
        chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('dist/index.html')});
      }
    });
  });

});
```

what this code is doing is opening a new tab if no matching tab exists, otherwise set the matching tab as active.

However, if the matching tab is in a different window than the current one, I want to let the user know, otherwise they might be really confused since they don't have any other visual confirmation.

When I display the alert, this is what it looks like:

[image]

Is there any way to style this alert message? Is there another way to create an alert message that can be styled somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can change what the alert function does:

```
window.alert = function (message) {
  // Do something with message
};
```

You cannot change the title, styles or other behavior of the modal window launched by the native alert function.

What you can do - create a custom component(dialog, just a regular HTML element) and insert it into the page with Content Script. And from background page just send a message to display this custom dialog.

Comment: maybe there is a way to use the currentWindow to display the alert in the right window?

Comment: There are two possible ways to do it in the right window: 1) Use [`executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) 2) Send message to the content script on this tab and execute it from there